# Ionic card item text not showing on android 5

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic card to show some reports ans statistics (with chartjs). It works perfectly on browser and android 4.4.2, but the text is not showing on android 5.
Screen shot of application running on android 4.4.2:

[image]

Screen shot of application running on android 5:

[image]

Here is my specs: 
ionic v: 2.1.1
cordova v: 6.3.1 
Nodejs v: v4.2.6

And here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="list card">

        <a class="item item-icon-left bg-blue color-white">
          <i class="icon ion-pricetag"></i>
          CA
        </a>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-40 clotureInfo">
            <div class="row light-bg">
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item">CA Global</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item price"> {{globalData.caGlobal}}€</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-10"> <a class="item"> <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i></a></div>
              <div class="col col-40">
                <a class="item"> Vente directes</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item price"> {{globalData.venteDirecte}}€</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row light-bg">
              <div class="col col-10"></div>
              <div class="col col-40">
                <a class="item"> Nb tickets</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item price"> {{globalData.nbTickets}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-10"></div>
              <div class="col col-40">
                <a class="item"> Tickets moyen</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item price" ng-if="globalData.nbTickets>0"> {{(globalData.venteDirecte / globalData.nbTickets).toFixed(2)}}€</a>
                <a class="item price" ng-if="globalData.nbTickets==0"> 0</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row light-bg">
              <div class="col col-10"> <a class="item"> <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i></a></div>
              <div class="col col-40">
                <a class="item"> Vente resto</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item price"> {{globalData.venteResto}}€</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-10"></div>
              <div class="col col-40">
                <a class="item"> Nb couverts</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item price"> {{globalData.nbCouverts}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row light-bg">
              <div class="col col-10"></div>
              <div class="col col-40">
                <a class="item"> Moy couverts</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-50">
                <a class="item price"> {{(globalData.venteResto / globalData.nbCouverts).toFixed(2)}}€</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col col-50">
            <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
              chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-colors="globalData.colors2">
            </canvas> 
          </div>
          <div class="col col-10">
            <p class="rec-color"> <span ng-style="{background: globalData.colors2[0]}"></span> Vente resto </p>
            <p class="rec-color"> <span ng-style="{background: globalData.colors2[1]}"></span> Vente directe</p>
          </div>  
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried to show the text using css style using z-index and color with !important but it deosn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where a conflict between css class "card" and the chartjs. 
It worked in this two cases:

- When i removed the chartjs canvas
- When i removed the card css class

So i removed the card and i used a custom css code.

But why it worked fine on android 4.4.2 and there was a bug on android 5?